# How to display data from multiple table with php

Tags: php, html

Here is my Song.php code which i created a class so i can use it in the index.php file

```
<?php
require_once("dbInfo.php");
Class Song{
    public $length; 
    public $picture;
    public $urlSong;
 
    public $songId;

 
    public $lastname;
    
    
    
   public static function getAllRecords($pageNo, $pageSize, &$totalRecords) {

        // Connect to database.
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dsn = "mysql:host=" . DatabaseInfo::getServer() . ";dbname=" . DatabaseInfo::getDatabaseName() . ";charset=utf8";
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, DatabaseInfo::getUserName(), DatabaseInfo::getPassword(), $options);



        $pageNo = (int)$pageNo;
        $pageSize = (int)$pageSize;

        $sql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Count
                FROM    `
(SELECT song.SongId,song.Picture,song.Length,song.UrlSong,artist.Lastname FROM song LEFT JOIN
  songandartist on song.SongId= songandartist.SongId INNER JOIN artist on                                         songandartist.ArtistId=artist.ArtistId)AS T1`";

        // Prepare statement.
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        // Execute the statement.
        $stmt->execute();

        // Get total records count.
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $totalRecords = $row['Count'];
        $stmt = NULL;

        $totalPages = ceil($totalRecords / $pageSize);
        if ($pageNo > $totalPages) {
            $pageNo = $totalPages;
        }

        $start = $pageSize * $pageNo - $pageSize;
        if($start < 0) {
            $start = 0;
        }

        $sql = "SELECT `Length`,`Picture`,`SongId`,`Lastname`,`UrlSong` FROM
                    


`(SELECT song.SongId,song.Picture,song.Length,song.UrlSong,artist.Lastname FROM song left join songandartist on song.SongId= songandartist.SongId INNER JOIN artist on songandartist.ArtistId=artist.ArtistId)AS T1`
                
                LIMIT $start, $pageSize;";

        // Prepare statement.
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        // Execute the statement.
        $stmt->execute();

        // Fetch all records.
        $list = Array();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $song = new GetAllSong();

            $song->length = $row["Length"];
            $song->picture = $row["Picture"];
            $song->songId = $row["SongId"];
            $song->lastname = $row["Lastname"];
            $song->urlSong = $row["UrlSong"];

            array_push($list, $song);
        }

        // Close the database connection.
        $conn = NULL;

        return $list;
    }
        
        
          
    
}

?>
```

And here is my index.php code, i called the class and used the function but it did not work

```
<?php
include '../Song.php';
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row py-5">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
            <div class="p-5 rounded shadow "
                 style="border-radius: 1rem;background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.58);">
                <h2 class="mb-5">Table Song</h2>

                <div class="p-1 bg-light rounded rounded-3 shadow-sm mb-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-describedby="button-addon1" class="form-control border-0 bg-light">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button id="button-addon1" type="submit" class="btn btn-link text-primary"><strong><i class="bi bi-search"></i></strong></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form  class="col-lg-8"name="get_Song" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?page=listsong" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-row mb-4 align-items-center">
                        <!--      <label class="fs-5 fw-bold text-secondary mr-0" for="inlineFormInput">Page No</label>-->
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-2 border-0" name="PageNo" id="PageNoid" placeholder="Page No">
                        </div>
                        <!--      <label class="fs-5 fw-bold text-secondary mr-0" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Page Size</label> -->
                        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg  mb-2 border-0" name="PageSize" id="Pagesizeid" placeholder="Page Size">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info mb-2 form-control-lg fs-5 fw-bold" id="ResetId" name="reset" value="Reset" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="table-responsive custom-table-responsive">

                    <table class="table custom-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    <label class="control control--checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="js-check-all" />
                                        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                                    </label>
                                </th class="">
                                <th scope="col">SongId</th>
                                <th scope="col">Lastname</th>
                                <th scope="col">Length</th>
                                <th scope="col">Picture</th>
                                <th scope="col">UrlSong</th>
                         
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <?php
                            $pageNo = 1;
                            $pageS = 4;

                            if (!empty($_POST['reset'])) {
                                $pageNo = $_POST['PageNo'];
                                $pageS = $_POST['PageSize'];
                            }
                            $getdb = new Song();
                            $arr = $getdb->getAllRecords($pageNo, $pageS, $totalRecords);
//                            $strTbl = "";
//
//                            $stt = 1;

                            for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
                                $obj = $arr[$i];
                                ?>
                                <tr scope='row'>
                                    <th scope="row">
                                        <label class="control control--checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" />
                                            <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                                        </label>
                                    </th>
                                    <td> <?php echo $obj->songId ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $obj->lastname ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $obj->length ?></td>
                                    <td>  <?php echo $obj->picture ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $obj->urlSong ?></td>
                                    <td>


                                        <div style='display:flex;'>
                                            <a href="Admin.php?page=addsong&id=<?php echo $obj->songId; ?>" class='btn btn-info mr-1' id='updatef'><i class='i bi-arrow-repeat'></i></a>
                                            <a href="../backend/delete/delsong.php?id=<?php echo $obj->songId; ?>" class='btn btn-danger mr-1' id='deletef'><i class='bi bi-trash'></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>                                            
                                <tr class="spacer"><td colspan="100"></td> </tr>
<?php } ?>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['reset'])) {
    echo "Page : " . $pageNo . " " . "Size: " . $pageS;
}
;
?>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display multiple tables from the database with these code, but it did not work, it only showed the blank page without any errors when i click the button. I tried to change the sql to echo `test` and it worked, so i think the problem in my code is that i did not use the right sql statement.Please help me with this, thank you very much.

Comment: "It won't work" is very broad. Please use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us the error. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Sorry for being vague i will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of problems.

First, in index.php you're calling an instance method, rather than a static method.  Instead of

```
$getdb = new Song();
$arr = $getdb->getAllRecords($pageNo, $pageS, $totalRecords);
```

You should use

```
$arr = Song::getAllRecords($pageNo, $pageS, $totalRecords);
```

... but that's not what's causing your error.

In your class definition, you have

```
$song = new GetAllSong();
```

but I think it should be

```
$song = new Song();
```

Also although I can't see an error with your SQL, I'm not sure why you're using a nested query.  It might be easier and more peformant to use a simple SQL statement?

Edit: Also you have an SQL injection vulnerability.  You're taking whatever someone has POSTed and passing it directly into your SQL statement.  If someone crafts a malicious POST request to your web page they could perform whatever SQL they wanted to on your database.